# How to link CSS file available on any web server in a link tag of html code

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='animation.css-css'  href='http://isconbalajifoods.com/wp-content/themes/proxima/css/animation.css?ver=d52801ed0870d60c78a8f986cba15dc7' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In above code there is a reference of `animation.css` file is given to `href` attribute of link tag but I don't understand  that given path of animation.css file where exactly this file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

It's on an external server, exactly at the given URL, independent from the website that page is on.